# PostGIS Raster Tile Size Affects ST_Intersect?

Tags: postgis, gdal

My understanding of tiles in PostGIS rasters had been that they optimize the speed of calculations, so I was confused to run into an example where the choice of tile size actually changed the results of an intersect.

I am trying to find the value of `myraster` at the points in `mypoints_tbl`, but found that some points did not intersect with the raster, even though they appeared to when viewed in ArcMap.

In addition, I found that different tile sizes produced different numbers of points that don't intersect.

For example:

```
$ raster2pgsql -s 26958 -d -I -C -M myraster.tif -t 100x100 myraster_tbl | psql -q
$ psql -c "select count(*) from mypoints_tbl left join myraster_tbl on st_intersects(rast, geom) where st_value(rast, geom) is null;"

 count
-------
 8

$ raster2pgsql -s 26958 -d -I -C -M myraster.tif -t 1000x1000 myraster2_tbl | psql -q
$ psql -c "select count(*) from mypoints left join myraster2_tbl on st_intersects(rast, geom) where st_value(rast, geom) is null;"

 count
-------
 0

$ raster2pgsql -s 26958 -d -I -C -M myraster.tif -t auto myraster3_tbl | psql -q
$ psql -c "select count(*) from mypoints left join myraster3_tbl on st_intersects(rast, geom) where st_value(rast, geom) is null;"

 count
-------
 9
```

I can get more values of `count` for other tile sizes.

What am I misunderstanding about tile size and st_intersect in this case? It's not clear to me at all why one should affect the other.

Comment: What are the original width and height of your raster?

Comment: Running gdalinfo on the tif file gave: Size is 10636, 28744, Pixel Size = (28.264051868594269,-30.869817405340033)

Comment: What is the the output of `SELECT ST_Metadata(rast) FROM gids.exampletable LIMIT 1`?